# Access Virtual Appliance through ip, running on vm inside Hyper-v on top of a vm from Azure

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine

I have a Vm from Azure and in that vm I have another vm running in Hyper-v. That vm in Hyper-v is running a Ubuntu Linux (64 bit) guest operating system, with a virtual appliance. When I run it and it is finished booting, I'm given a IP address like this: "https://10.8.40.104/4442". The problem is I'm not able to access it from inside my 1 vm from Azure. I tried pulling up the browser and pasting the address, but nothing. I am quite new at this so its possible the solution is fairly simple.

Anyone have any idea how I can access that static IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Hyper-V in Azure Nested Virtualization, you could follow steps in [this blog](https://www.vembu.com/blog/running-hyper-v-in-azure-nested-virtualization/):

> There are (7) short steps that need to be completed to provision a
>   nested virtual machine inside Microsoft Azure:
>
> - Create an Azure VM capable of nesting (Windows Server 2016, etc)
> - Connect to the Azure VM
> - Install Hyper-V Feature inside the Azure VM
> - Create a NAT’ed vSwitch for outside connectivity
> - Create the guest virtual machine
> - Configure an IP Address on the nested guest virtual machine
> - Test Connectivity

For allowing connectivity to the nested virtual machine from outside, you need to create a new virtual switch that will be configured for NAT’ed access. The network flow will be like this: outside---host public IP---host private IP---NAT internal switch---Internal gateway---nested VM private IP.

Feel free to let me know if this helps or need further help.